# What's the correct usage of DateTime and DateTimeZone?

Tags: php, timezone

Any idea why the following:

```
$objTimeZone = new DateTimezone("Europe/London");

$objDateFrom = new DateTime(null);
$objDateFrom->setTimezone($objTimeZone); 
$date_from = $objDateFrom->format('c');

$objDateTo = new DateTime(strtotime("2011-05-04 19:30:00 - 24 hour"));
$objDateTo->setTimezone($objTimeZone); 
$date_to = $objDateTo->format('c');
```

would give me the following for $date_from:

> 2011-03-18T14:34:19+00:00

which seems fine, and the following for $date_to - which is obviously wrong:

> 1000-03-18T13:04:45+00:00

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, use `format('c:');` instead! Joking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) does not accept a UNIX timestamp as its first constructor argument. It instead expects a string like the one put into `strtotime()`. So your code should read:

```
$objTimeZone = new DateTimezone("Europe/London");

// ...

$objDateTo = new DateTime("2011-05-04 19:30:00 - 24 hour");
$objDateTo->setTimezone($objTimeZone); 
$date_to = $objDateTo->format('c');
```

To use `DateTime` with a timestamp you have to precede the timestamp with a `@`:

```
$ts = time();
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$ts);
```

**By the way:** you have to be careful with the way you're creating the `DateTime` object and applying the timezone. You're creating the `DateTime` object in the default timezone (which is set via the [`php.ini`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) or via [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). You then apply the `Europe/London` timezone onto this `DateTime` object which actually is: *take the the point in time `2011-05-04 19:30:00 - 24 hour` in my default configured timezone and we then want to know what time this point in time is in the `Europe/London` timezone.* There is no difference if you configured timezone is in fact `Europe/London`but it may be a difference if the timezones differ.

**EDIT** (to make an example)

Your system is configured with a default timezone of `UTC`.

```
$date1 = new DateTime(); // the null doesn't matter
// $date1 now contains approx. 2011-03-18T15:03:58+00:00
$date1->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/London');
// $date1 doesn't change because UTC is the same as Europe/London for the given date
$date1->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Berlin');
// in Germany the same point in time is 2011-03-18T16:03:58+01:00
```

No problem so far. Let's take your second date.

```
$date2 = new DateTime("2011-05-04 19:30:00 - 24 hour");    
// $date2 now contains 2011-05-03T19:30:00+00:00
$date2->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/London');
// $date2 now changes to 2011-05-03T20:30:00+01:00 because Europe/London moves to DST on March 27th
$date2->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Berlin');
// that's 2011-05-03T21:30:00+02:00 in Germany
```

Hoe that clears that one up a bit.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: Nicely explained, +1.

Comment: Thanks Stefan - I've amended the code as per your instructions but now I'm getting the following results: $date_from: 2011-03-18T14:44:51+00:00 / $date_to: 2011-05-03T20:30:00+01:00 - as you can see the $date_to has different time zone - even thou they both use the same one - any idea?

Comment: I use : date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); in the config and then run the code above. My server is in "Europe/London" timezone, but not all of the events are - this is why I need to define the timezone for these two dates to pass them over to PayPal. I don't think I quite understand what you're try to say by the "by the way" part - it should work if you're defining the time zone manually - right? The fact is that even thou I'm using "Europe/London" timezone for both - I'm getting $date_to with the difference -01:00 (my current results are: 2011-03-18T15:01:10+00:00 > 2011-05-03T19:30:00+01:00)

Comment: `Europe/London` will change to DST on March 27th. Before March 27th `Europe/London` will be the same as `UTC` so you don't see a difference if you move date 1 from `UTC` into `Europe/London`. After March 27th there is a difference between `UTC` and `Europe/London` so you'll see a difference in the timezone offset.

Comment: What would you suggest then? How can I reinforce the offset?

Comment: That depends. In which timezone are the date values given? And which timezone do you want to use for output?